# Converting a list of "stuff" to a single string

Tags: python, string, casting, output

This is a pretty basic question, but I have looked in three tutes and can't find an answer.  I have a bunch of "items": "The value is ", 54, and ".  Do you agree?" where 54 is an integer, not a string.  All I want to do is put them together into one string:

"The value is 54.  Do you agree?\n"

The only way I have found to do this is

```
>>> strlist=['The value is ', 54, '.  Do you agree?', '\n']
>>> singlestring=''.join(map(str,strlist))
>>> print singlestring
The value is 54 .  Do you agree?
```

So it works, but I keep thinking surely there is a simpler way to do this.  Anyone know what that would be?  Thanks.

Comment: That's about as good as it gets.  Of course, there are variants:  `''.join(str(x) for x in strlist)`, but ultimately, it's basically the same thing.

Comment: You can always start defining custom functions in a `utils.py` like `stringify(lst)` that you just import into all your projects for the sake of convenience.

Comment: OK, understood, though I'm surprised.  Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mgilson says:

```
''.join(str(x) for x in strlist)
```

is more 'pythonic' as I don't think map is so widely liked anymore. It also generalises more to the case where you didn't have a list but some other iterable thing.

Comment: Thanks.  As they said in "Fargo", "That's a surprise!"